# Is $x\cdot\sin x$ bounded or not on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can only go forward to $|x|\cdot|\sin x|\le|x|\cdot|x|$ equation.How can I understand that this function is bounded or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $\sin\left(\frac \pi 2 + 2k\pi\right) = 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb Z$. Setting 
$x = \frac \pi 2 + 2k\pi$ we get
$$  x \sin(x)  =  \left(\frac \pi 2 + 2k \pi \right)\sin\left(\frac \pi 2 + 2 k \pi\right) = \frac \pi 2 + 2k \pi $$
which clearly is unbounded for $k \in \mathbb Z \subset \mathbb R$. Thus your function is not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $-1 ≤ \sin x ≤ 1$.

This means at some points $x \sin x = x$, and since $x$ can get arbitrarily large, then $x \sin x$ also can get arbitrarily large. From this, is your function bounded?

Comment: What's wrong with my proof? It would be nice to point out any mistakes I might have made, so that I can edit them.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding - the question asks if $x * \sin x$ is bounded, but he then tried $|x| * |\sin x|$. Either way, the question is still about $x * \sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to compare it would be with $f(x)=|x|$ since $|\sin x|\le1$ we get $|x||\sin x|\le|x|$.

Of course, as shown by Stefan, the function is unbounded.

Intuitively you can see that $|x||\sin x|$ periodically matches the values of $f(x)=|x|$ and $f(x)$ is obviously unbounded.

A graph that might illustrate it better-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$x_n = (π/2)+2πn $.

$y_n := x_n\sin(x_n) = (π/2) +2πn.$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } y_n =\infty.$

Is there a lower bound for $ x \sin x $ ?