# Showing that $f(x) = x\sin(x)$ is not bounded above.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I'm trying to show that $f(x) = x\sin(x)$ is not bounded above. I'm given the following definition : f is bounded above if and only if $∃M∈R$, $∀x∈R$, $f(x)≤M$.

Can someone please confirm if my reasoning is correct?

I assumed $f(x) = x\sin(x)$ is bounded above.
So by definition, $∃M∈R$, $∀x∈R$, $f(x)≤M$.

So $x\sin(x)≤M$.

Thus, $\sin(x)\le \frac{M}x$

If we choose $x = \frac{-M}2$ then we would have $\sin(\frac{-M}2) \le -2$.

However, that's impossible because we have $-1\le \sin(\frac{-M}2) \le 1$.

So $f(x) = x\sin(x)$ is not bounded above.

Thanks for any and all feedback.

Comment: What if $x$ were negative?  Then the inequality would flip.  You then have $\sin\left( \frac{-M}{2} \right) \geq -2$ which is not a contradiction.

Comment: My recommendation: Forget contradiction. Find a concrete sequence $x_n\to\infty$ with $f(x_n)\to\infty$.

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect. As $-M/2<0$ you get $\sin(-M/2)\geq M/x$. But rather a hint: Try to choose your $x$ is such a way that $\sin(x)=1$, and reason that $x$ can be choosen arbitrarily large.

Comment: @TedShifrin is right.  Because of the $x$ out front it's not hard to make this grow.

Comment: The same question has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510499/is-x-cdot-sin-x-bounded-or-not-on-mathbb-r?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=(2\lceil |M|\rceil+1/2)\pi$$

$$\sin x=1$$

$$x\sin x=(2\lceil |M|\rceil+1/2)\pi > 2\pi\lceil |M|\rceil\geq 2\pi|M|\geq |M| \geq M$$

$$x\sin x > M$$